# Set P4 View from batch script

Tags: batch-file, perforce

I'd like to be able set the view of the p4 client (as in the output of 'p4 client -o') programmatically from a batch script.

I'm sure it would be easy in unix (one line) [See update 2] but how can I do it in windows without installing 3rd party software (e.g. grep / sed) or writing a C# program to do it (which seems overkill for the simplicity of what I'd like to do).

UPDATE :

The command above outputs comments along with settings like this;

```
#  View:        Lines to map depot files into the client workspace.

View: Path_to_depot Path_to_local
```

The logic I'd like to apply then is

```
For each line in output
if line.substring(0,5) equals "View:"
replace line with %newviewsetting%
```

Or if it's easier

```
split output with space as delimiter
if the node equals "View:" and previous node not equal to #
set the next node to %myPathToDepotSetting%
```

UPDATE 2 :

in unix the command would be

```
p4 client -o | sed 's/^View:.*/View: New view/' | p4 client -i
```

Which is effectively saying;
Output the text to the command line 
Replace lines starting with View with my new View 
Input it back to p4

Comment: You say replace line as if you are working with a file. But you are dealing with the output of a command. So I don't understand where you want to put your end result. Also, your two proposed approaches would not give the same result, so I am very confused.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit unclear as to exactly what you are trying to do. I know nothing about perforce, but quite a bit about batch files.

If you need to programmatically work with the output of `p4 client -o` then you want the FOR /F command. You can get FOR documentation by typing `help for` or `for /?` from a Windows command prompt.

For example, the following would simply echo the output of the command to the screen, disregarding blank lines and lines that begin with the default EOL character (`;`). But obviously much more can be done.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('p4 client -o') do (
  echo %%A
)
```

The FOR command is a bit of a beast with a lot of non-intutive solutions for its many eccentricities. If you provide a clearer explanation as to what you need to do, then I might be able to provide better guidance.

Comment: Thanks dbenham, I think that's what I'm after, I added extra info above

Answer (score 0):

This is considerably easier if you can use one of the Perforce APIs.  That way you won't be doing so much text parsing in batch.  Are you comfortable with perl, python, ruby, or .net?